# d3.js calendar view - colours + custom date

Tags: d3.js, calendar

I have a few questions regarding his calendar view of mine
http://bl.ocks.org/mhska/5333055

[image]

data ranges from 1 to 4317 so the colours are not very "evenly" distributed. is there any way to improve it? (i mean basically everything below 100 is just one red colour)

is there a way to change the date format when you hover over the field from yyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy?

how could one change the colour of fields with no data? (generally this means weekends)
at the moment the fileds with no data and with most data (over 1000) are of the same colour.

thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the date format that is displayed by adapting the line

```
date = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")
```

More information on the specifiers can be found in [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format).

For changing the colour, you need to provide a different function for mapping values to colours. It looks like you're currently mapping your input values to only 40 output colours.

```
.range(d3.range([40]))
```

Increasing this number might be a good starting point. Note that you can provide an arbitrary function, in particular you could handle missing values separately in it.

Comment: thanks Lars Kotthoff.
i tried to change the date - it showed as expected on the hover, but it didnt load the data anymore :)
I increased the range to 400, but as you can see, it didnt help much
http://bl.ocks.org/mhska/5333055
(anything above 40 gives only more white spots)

Comment: You're linking to the same block -- I can't see the changes you've made. What error message did you get when it didn't load the data?

Comment: Ok, this doesn't work because you're using explicit CSS classes for the colours. You should have a look at using scales that create colours. You could for example map your input to the (0,1) interval and [interpolate between two colours](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolateRgb).